# asp.net Request.Browser.Browser returning as mozilla in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I have an issue with IE11 browser detection.

I'm using `Request.Browser.Browser` to get the name of it, but it returns as `Mozilla`.

Please advice!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911175/ie-11-browser-recognizes-itself-as-mozilla

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375671/detecting-ie11-with-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer identifies itself as a Mozilla browser.

Check here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537503.aspx

Hope, It helps you. Have a nice day. :)